# Can't install app (Error code: -505)

Tags: android, google-play

I have 2 applications with the different package name and different keystore, uploaded in play store. Unable to install both applications in a single phone, if i install both in different phones it works fine. If i try to install both applications in same phone, the first application will install without problem and works fine, but second application shows Can't install app (Error code: -505).

Android OS - 6.0.1

Comment: can you comment both app link

Comment: Hi yatish! Did you managed to solve the issue?

Comment: it started working after changing versionName of one application

Comment: Thank you man! you saved my day. I forgot to change my category name in receiver code for OneSignal's GCM Broadcast receiver in Manifest file while replicating my Xamarin app.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect your Android device to your computer, run Android Studio & [open a logcat window](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html).  It'll log verbose information regarding the error you're encountering.

For instance, we were seeing the following error associated w/ a -505:

`11-09 09:50:18.952 2344-2344/? E/installd: Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl313443419.tmp: No such file or directory
11-09 09:50:18.952 31448-31448/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.cb.i.onReceive(21): Error -505 while installing live.redacted.Redacted: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/live.redacted.Redacted-1: Can't install because provider name live.redacted.Redacted.fileprovider (in package live.redacted.Redacted) is already used by live.redacted.Redacted.dev
11-09 09:50:18.982 31448-31448/? W/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.installer.a.ag.a(62): Install failure of live.redacted.Redacted (isid: 4o_xSNWRTTSsO2t7F3heig): -505, Exception: n/a`